# Generate methods to forward calls of interface methods in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have an interface `Foo` as follows

```
public interface Foo {

    void methodA();
    void methodB();
    void methodC();        

}
```

I also have a class `Bar` implementing `Foo`, but I want the methods of Foo to be forwarded to a member of type `Foo` instead of implementing them directly or extending a concrete class that implements `Foo`:

```
public class Bar implements Foo {

    private Foo foo;

    void methodA() {
        foo.methodA();
    }

    // ...and so on...

}
```

But I'm too lazy to type out each forwarding method, and this pattern seems common enough that I thought there must be a way to do this automagically - only I can't figure out how. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans can accomplish this with a few mouse clicks.

1. Right click in the body of class Bar
2. Select **Insert Code...**
3. Select **Delegate Method...**
4. In the left pane of the popup dialog, select the Foo member
5. In the right pane, check all of Foo's methods that you would like to generate delegate methods for.
6. Click **Generate**

If you prefer keyboard shortcuts, just type **Alt-Insert** to show the insert code menu instead.